# Translating XML Nodes with order

Tags: xml, xslt

XML Input:

```
<a>
    <b>text_b</b>
    <d>text_d</d>
    <c>text_c</c>
    <e>text_e</e>
    <d>text_d</d>
    <f>text_f</f>
</a>
<g>
    <b>text_b</b>
    <d>text_d</d>
    <c>text_c</c>
    <e>text_e</e>
    <d>text_d</d>
    <f>text_f</f>
</g>
```

Desired Output:

```
<aa>
    <aaa>
        <some_extra_tag>some_text</some_extra_tag>
        <aab>text_b</aab>
    </aaa>
    <aad>text_d</aad>
    <aaa>
        <some_extra_tag>some_text</some_extra_tag>
        <aac>text_c</aac>
        <aae>text_e</aae>
    </aaa>
    <aad>text_d</aad>
    <aaa>
        <some_extra_tag>some_text</some_extra_tag>
        <aaf>text_f</aaf>
    </aaa>
</aa>
<gg>
    <aab>text_b</aab>
    <ggg>
        <some_extra_tag2>some_text</some_extra_tag2>
        <aad>text_d</aad>
    </ggg>
    <aac>text_c</aac>
    <aae>text_e</aae>
    <ggg>
        <some_extra_tag2>some_text</some_extra_tag2>
        <aad>text_d</aad>
    </ggg>
    <aaf>text_f</aaf>
</gg>
```

can i use XSLT to translate the above XML Input to the desired output?
Limitations:
the some_extra_tag-Tag should be generated by a-Tag-Template and some_extra_tag2-Tag by g-Tag-Template.

Comment: So you're saying you want to put each `inner` and `middle` in its own `outer` element, and put the `inner`s inside `span`s? You haven't really explained what you want to do.

Comment: what i want to do is actually just to keep the ordering as it was,
I do know if i use <xsl:apply-templates select="inner|middle" /> the ordering will be kept, however i cannot do that because the <span> is generated on the outer-Template.

Actually it does not really matter whether the middle-Tag has its own outer-Tag.
For clarification, i have editer my question.

Comment: Your question is (still) not clear. The example is ambiguous - what are the **rules** for the transformation?

Comment: @michael.hor257k is it clear enough now? sorry that the question was never clear enough because i really do not want to include the details.

Answer (score 2):

What (I think) you are trying to do is a bit tricky, but I believe the following should do it. It works by using a recursive template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- standard identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*" name="Copy">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="outer">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::inner)] |
                                   inner[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::inner])]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="inner[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::inner])]">
    <span>
      <xsl:call-template name="Copy" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::inner]" />
    </span>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="inner">
    <xsl:call-template name="Copy" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::inner]" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on this input:

```
<outer>
  <inner>text first</inner>
  <inner>text second</inner>
  <middle>text third</middle>
  <inner>text fourth</inner>
</outer>
```

It produces the result:

```
<outer>
  <span>
    <inner>text first</inner>
    <inner>text second</inner>
  </span>
  <middle>text third</middle>
  <span>
    <inner>text fourth</inner>
  </span>
</outer>
```

Comment: wait, there seem to be some mistake, i did mention that span-Tag need to be generated on outer-Tag right?

Comment: @sstephen My XSLT produces the output you listed under "desired output". If your desired output is something else, please clarify that and _explain your requirement_.

Comment: yes, it does produce the right output, however it is neglecting my requirement (i have edited my question)

Comment: @sstephen What does "I need to generate span-Tag through outer-Tag" mean? Can you provide an input and output where my solution does not produce the needed result?

Comment: please read my question more carefully, i have written a simple example for it, namely under "Such like:".

I think I have over-simplified the question, this is the situation where my requirement is needed and your answer doesnt fit:

beside inner-Tag there is inner2-Tag and both of them need to be inside the same span-Tag.

...<span><inner>text</inner><inner2>text</inner2></span>...

Comment: @sstephen I have read your question 10 times, and it doesn't matter how many times I read it; your description of your requirement consists of 7 words and even those 7 words don't make sense. You need to learn how to clarify your requirements, especially when someone is asking you to _clarify your requirements_. At any rate, please see my updated answer. I think that it does what you are talking about.

Comment: sry, but i still cannot understand the _clarify your requirements_ stuff, however i already edited my question and it is  very close to my actual problem. Thank you very much for your hard work to even try to answer my unclear question.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

      <xsl:template match="outer">
        <doc>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </doc>
      </xsl:template>


      <xsl:template match="*">
        <outer>
          <span>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </span>
        </outer>
      </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doc>
  <outer>
    <span>
      <inner>text first</inner>
    </span>
  </outer>
  <outer>
    <span>
      <middle>text second</middle>
    </span>
  </outer>
  <outer>
    <span>
      <inner>text third</inner>
    </span>
  </outer>
</doc>
```

Comment: Your output matches neither the current requested output nor the original requested output.

Comment: Why? what is wrong with my output? Doc tag added for XML to be valid